# netty bootstrap connection refused

Tags: java, client, netty

trying to connect client `io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap`:

```
ChannelFuture cf = null;
cf = m_bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress
            .getByName("127.0.0.1"), 8084));
```

in cf, `result` : `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:8084`
detailed message:

> [sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method),
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599),
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:208),
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:287),
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528),
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468),
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382),
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354),
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116),
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)]

my /etc/hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1>--localhost
255.255.255.255>broadcasthost
::1             localhost-
****::1%lo*>localhost
127.0.0.1>--********
```

Not sure what to do? literally assumed I can pass localhost and port and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is something really listing on the port ?

Try:

telnet 127.0.0.1 8084

Answer (score 0):

turns out in MAC since the server binds to my IP address and not localhost or 127.0.0.1 it would not accept the the client to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1. 
It worked fine when I replaced loopback addr with my IP. Strange but guess it is something to do with difference interfaces in MAC. Not sure how Windows would react.